# Why are my tables unavailable in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a single RDB (rethinkdb 2.1.1~0trusty) instance on my VPS without cluster or shards with one database containing 6 tables. The web admin interface shows 7 issues: 1 for outdated indexes and 6 for the unavailable tables. Sometimes it happens that one must rebuild the table indexes due to RethinkDB server update, it happened before and I could rebuild them using the `rethinkdb index-rebuild` command.

But this time rebulding the indexes doesn't work because RDB keeps telling me my tables are unreachable, although the data dir seems intact. I'd like to know what to do to resolve these issues.

What I've tried so far:

- `rethinkdb index-rebuild` command which tells me my tables are unreachable
- `rethinkdb dump` to make a dump, recreate the database and the indexes by hand, but also tells me the tables are unreachable
- restart rethinkdb / restart my VPS - it's no use
- double check my instance configuration - directory points to the actual data dir, etc. so nothing special here
- double check permissions on data dir - it's also ok

What still works:

- reading/writing the tables using the Data Explorer
- read/write access by my web app

All in all, my RDB instance seems to be fully operational, but I cannot rebuild the indexes or create a dump and the admin interface is showing some issues I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: I think the important question is why the tables are not fully available. Where the tables replicated, and one server is missing?
Can you try reconfiguring all tables through `r.db('your_db_name').reconfigure({shards: 1, replicas: 1})` and see if that resolves the issue (you might want to use different values for `shards` and `replicas` depending on your cluster and requirements)?

Comment: Did you just update to 2.1.1? I had similar issues with indexes on 2.1.1 but I downgraded to 2.0.4 and everything works again.

Comment: @DanielMewes this results in `The server(s) hosting table 'your_db_name.votes' are currently unreachable.`

Comment: @janih Yes I did. I will try downgrading now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve all the issues by following @janih's advice in a comment on the original post to downgrade by doing the following:

```
# apt-get install rethinkdb=2.1.0+1~0trusty
# rethinkdb index-rebuild -a MYACCESSKEY -r my_database
# service rethinkdb restart
```

And tada! All the 7 issues shown by the admin UI went away!

**EDIT:** Finally upgrading to 2.1.2 solved the problem

Comment: This is probably the bug report https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4723 and will be fixed in 2.1.2

Comment: Quick update: We've released RethinkDB 2.1.2 which should fix this problem.